# Uniform boundedness for Strichartz constants in Tao's book

Tags: harmonic-analysis, schrodinger-operators, wave-equation

This is a question from Tao's book "Nonlinear Dispersive
Equations". We define the space $S^0(I\times R^d)$ as the closure of the Schwartz functions under the norm
$$\|u\|_{S^0}=\sup_{(q,r)\text{ admissable}}\|u\|_{L_t^q L_x^r}, $$
where $(q,r)$ is an admissible Strichartz pair satisfying $\frac{2}{q}+\frac{d}{r}=\frac{d}{2}$. Denote by $N^0$ the dual space of $S^0$. Now consider the Schrödinger equation
$$i\partial_t u+\Delta u=F $$ 
with initial datum $u_0$. It is claimed that using Duhamel and Strichartz we have 
$$\|u\|_{S^0}\lesssim_{d}\|u_0\|_{L_x^2}+\|F\|_{N^0} $$
((3.26) in the book). What makes me confused is the index $d$, which says that the estimate constant should only depend on the space dimension. I don't see this directly from the Strichartz estimates stated in Tao's book. By those Strichartz estiamtes in the book ((2.24) to (2.26)), the estimate constants should also depend on the precise choice of the admissable pairs but not only on the space dimension. I observe that by the footnote "23" (p. 134), it is cautioned that some issues may occur in the case $d=2$, since the set of admissable pairs is not **compact**. So my guess would be that the Strichartz constants should depend continuously on the pair $(q,r)$, and the uniform boundedness follows. In fact, the set for $(q,r)$ is also unbounded, but I quess it is meant for the set of the pairs $(\frac{1}{q},\frac{1}{r})$, where compactness holds due to the relation $\frac{2}{q}+\frac{d}{r}=\frac{d}{2}$. However, I don't see the continuous dependence of the Strichartz estimates on the pairs from the proof given in the book.

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Standard interpolation theorems (e.g., Riesz-Thorin) will give uniform bounds on the constants in the Strichartz estimates in terms of the constants of the endpoint Strichartz estimates (and in fact these interpolation theorems show that the best constants do indeed vary continuously, although uniform boundedness suffices for applications).  As noted, when $d=2$ the endpoint is missing and one needs to modify norms such as $S^0$ either by restricting to a compact set of exponents, or inserting an appropriate weight that depends on the Strichartz constants.

Comment: @TerryTao Thank you very much Prof. Tao for your quick reply. The idea of interpolation perfectly explains how it works.